# accidentally remove reference from an xib. file in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, reference, xib

I was having an issue with my stimulator response to my coding and decided to try to modify my original connections in my xib. file to my IBOutlets

instead I ended up removing the reference to my FeedViewController .xib file. I try deleting my FeedViewController.Swift and recreating it again. but upon doing so I'm still missing my .xib file.

How can I restore my reference connection to my .xib file to display in my files!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you have only removed the reference, you can re-add the file with: `File -> Add files to "your project"`, then locate the xib in the window that appears.

Answer (score 2):

If it is in trash can, then you can easily restore it.

If you click “remove reference”, then you may have a chance to find it back in the folder: Project_folder -> Base.iproj -> Main.storyboard.
(I just found it back thx god)

Comment: thanx.. it helped me.. I deleted my Main.storyboard by clicking "remove reference".. then added the file File -> Add files to "your project" from Base.iproj

Comment: Glad that it helps, Good luck!